# Is there a way to get e.relatedTarget of bootstrap modal in document.ready ()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons that invoke the same modal, I have set `data-button` attribute to detect which button invoked the modal.

```
<button type="button" id="another" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-warning" data-button='another'>Add another</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-button="lab">Add  lab</button>
```

what I wanted to do is to change a label inside a modal depending on the button invoker. I did so :

```
<script>
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var $trigger = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $('#vv_type').val($trigger.data('button'));
    v_type = $trigger.data('button');
    if (v_type == 'lab') {
        $('#ModalLabel').html('changed label');
        $("label[for='id_date_of_label']").html('label inside modal changed');
    }
})
</script>
```

it works as expected only the first time when modal is shown , and after that the same changed label is always displayed whenever I click on the buttons, and this is logic due to `$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {`

Is there a way to declare `v_type` variable and send it to `document.ready()` function so that I make sure that the script will run every time I click on buttons invoking the modal (not only the first time?)

Comment: `e.relatedTarget` lives only at the time the event itself is alive, hence, not possible.

Comment: hmmm I see, so maybe  I have to create two different  modals with a different logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code still works for me. The only part missing is the `else` condition for `if (v_type == 'lab') {`. I can see the label change on each button click.

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
 var $trigger = $(e.relatedTarget);
 //$('#vv_type').val($trigger.data('button'));
 v_type = $trigger.data('button');
 
 if (v_type == 'lab') {
  $('#buttonText').html(v_type);
  //$("label[for='id_date_of_label']").html('label inside modal changed');
 }
 else
 {
  $('#buttonText').html(v_type);
  //$("label[for='id_date_of_label']").html('label inside modal changed');
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-button="lab" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<button type="button" data-button="lab 123" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <p id="buttonText"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by getting the `data-button` from a  hidden input `vv_type`  on the modal (my modal has already a form in it ) and I added this script which is ran each time a modal is shown:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            if ($('#vv_type').val() == 'lab') {
                 $('#ModalLabel').html('changed label');
    $("label[for='id_date_of_label']").html('label inside modal changed');
            }
            else {
                 $('#ModalLabel').html('origin label');
    $("label[for='id_date_of_label']").html('label inside modal origin');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```